# Salesforce Convert a Text to a Formula Field

Tags: formula, text

I want to change a Text Field to a picklist. I know how to actually change the field type however I have several Formula fields that reference the Text Field so when I try and change the field type, it states that I cannot because they are referenced in a Formula.

You cannot deactivate Formula Fields, I cannot change the Formula field to TEXT(Field__c) until the field is a picklist. How can this be handles is the only way to change the formula to a place holder reference then change the field type to a picklist and change the formula fields to reflect TEXT(Field__c)?

Comment: How about changing the field reference in the formulae to a string literal of the API name - `'Field__c'` rather than `Field__c` - updating the field type, then adjusting the formulae to `TEXT(Field__c)`?

Comment: Are you familiar with sfdx or the metadata api? You may be able to download the metadata for the necessary fields, make the changes directly in the xml files and then deploy all fields in one go.

Comment: @barrick You should add that as an answer

Comment: Thanks guys, that's kinda what I ended up doing was creating it as 'field'. Just kinda of a pain but I suppose that would happen in any IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the field reference in the formulae to a string literal of the API name - 'Field__c' rather than Field__c - updating the field type, then adjust the formulae to TEXT(Field__c)